# matrix of operators properties

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Let $T$ a self-adjoint operator bounded from below on $D(T)=H^2(\mathbb R)$ in the ambiant Hilbert space $\mathcal H=L^2(\mathbb R)$,  with essential spectrum $[0,+\infty)$ and for discret spectrum some bounded set of negative eigenvalues. Let $L$ the matrix operator defined by  $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
T & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$
on $\mathcal H \times \mathcal H$. I'm looking for properties of L, and I cannot conclude anything. What are the properties of $L$ : self​-adjoint, bounded, spectrum ?

Comment: What is $H^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @QuantumSpace Probably the [Sobolev space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#The_case_p_=_2) $W^{2,2}$

Comment: Is the operator $L$ symmetric to begin with?

Comment: With the usual scalar product on $\mathcal H$, $L$ is not symmetric.

Comment: $L^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}T & 0 \\ 0 & T\end{array}\right)$.